# jQuery UI Datepicker: Using DarkTheme not displaying month/year dropdown properly

Tags: css, jquery-ui, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm using jQuery UI Datepicker for my dob input. And it works flawlessly.

[image]

Then I realize there were other themes. So I downloaded this [Sleek Dark Theme](https://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#!zThemeParams=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) from its site.

I replaced all -

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/jquery-ui.theme.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="assets/js/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

But the month & year dropdown is not displaying correctly; white background, white text.

[image]

Obviously, it's the css. But I did replace all the files. Like three times to be sure. Did I miss something?

Thanks in advance!

---

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" id="txtDOB" name="customerDOB" class="form-control" placeholder="DD-MM-YYYY" maxlength="10" readonly>
<input type="hidden" id="txtDOBalt">
```

**JavaScript**

```
// Bind input box with datepicker
$(function () {
    $("#txtDOB").datepicker({
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '-120Y',
        maxDate: '-10Y',
        yearRange: '-120Y:-10Y',
        altField: "#txtDOBalt",
        altFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
        dateFormat: "dd-mm-yy",
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate the code you have tried?

Comment: @SauravRastogi I have updated my post with the codes.

Comment: Please create a pen or fiddle for this